# How can I tell nodemon to ignore all node_modules except for one directory

Tags: nodemon

I have a Node.js server I am developing and I'm using nodemon to have the server restarted when the source code changes.

This server has a dependency on another module, which I am also developing, so it would be nice if changes to that module also restarted the server.

**Best attempt yet** (Thanks, bitstrider!)

I made a repo to reproduce this problem with minimal code if anyone wants to check it out: https://github.com/shawninder/nodemon-troubles

The highlights are in `nodemon.json`:

```
{
  "ignoreRoot": [
    ".git",
    ".nyc_output",
    ".sass-cache",
    "bower-components",
    "coverage"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "node_modules/!(is-node)",
    "node_modules/is-node/node_modules"
  ]
}
```

- `ignoreRoot` is the same as [the defaults](https://github.com/novemberborn/ignore-by-default/blob/master/index.js), but without `node_modules`.
- `ignore` is where I'm trying to tell it to ignore node_modules, but not `is-node`.

This almost works (editing is-node restarts the server) but it's watching all the node modules, not only is-node.

How can I tell nodemon to ignore all node modules except for one?

**Details**

- I'm using the latest version of nodemon, 1.11.0
- I also tried with https://github.com/remy/nodemon/pull/922

**Explaining the problem**

Nodemon takes the ignores and combines them into one big regular expression before passing this along to chokidar. It's a custom parsing algorithm based on regular expressions and supports neither glob negation nor regular expression syntax. For example, the example above produces the following regular expression:

```
/\.git|\.nyc_output|\.sass\-cache|bower\-components|coverage|node_modules\/!\(is\-node\)\/.*.*\/.*|node_modules\/is\-node\/node_modules\/.*.*\/.*/
```

Notice the negation character `!` end up as a literal `!` in the resulting regular expression. Using negative look-ahead syntax also doesn't work because the control characters are transformed into literal characters.

Answer (score 3):

Since `nodemon` uses `minimatch` for matching, you should be able to use negation with the symbol `!`, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch/blob/master/README.md).

So in your case, try:

```
{
  "ignore" : "node_modules/!(my-watched-module)/**/*"
}
```

This should ignore all module *files* except those within `my-watched-module`

> NOTE: The `ignore` rule here **only targets files**, not directories.  This behavior makes sense in the context of `nodemon` because its watching for file changes.

Comment: Should but doesn't. In my latest attempt I am using the following in nodemon.json:
`{"ignoreRoot: [".git", ".nyc_output", ".sass-cache", "bower-components", "coverage"], "ignore": ["node_modules/!(my-watched-module)", "node_modules/my-watched-module/node_modules"]}`
It's correctly watching my-watched-module and not watching my-watched-module's node_modules, but it's still watching other node modules...

Comment: I edited my question with a link to a repo that reproduces the problem if you're interested

Comment: It's pretty strange since `ignoreRoot` clearly blacklists directories...

Comment: Your welcome! And yeah I agree, it would be more intuitive if `ignore` applied to directories.  But hey at least you're free to fork and add that feature

Comment: Damn it, this doesn't work in the non-simplified context. I will post again when I manage to reproduce the actual problem

Comment: I think I found out why this isn't working so I modified my question to add this in

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using NPM's built-in [workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) feature.

1. [Update NPM to the latest version](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm). ***NPM must be on at least version 7.x to use workspaces.***
2. If a `./node_modules` directory doesn't already exist, create it in your project's root folder.
3. Create a directory outside of `./node_modules` ([Nodemon ignores this directory by default](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#overriding-the-underlying-default-ignore-rules)) to house your under-development dependency module(s).

> For example, assuming Nodmon is running in the same folder as your project's `package.json` file, you could create a new folder named, `./node_modules_custom`, in the same directory.

4. Give each module ① its own `package.json` file and ② its own folder. NPM will rely on these `package.json` files to distinguish between your module(s) and anything else that may exist in the parent directory.

   ```
   My_Example_Node_Project/
   ├─ package.json/
   ├─ node_modules_custom/
   │  ├─ my_custom_module_1/
   │  │  ├─ package.json
   │  │  ├─ non_standard_main_file.js
   │  ├─ my_custom_module_2/
   │  │  ├─ package.json
   │  │  ├─ index.js
   ├─ node_modules/
   ├─ index.js
   ├─ .git/
   ├─ .gitignore
   ├─ .gitattributes
   ```
5. Designate the folder containing your under-development dependency modules as a workspace by adding the following three lines to `package.json`, where `node_modules_custom` is the name of the directory created in Step 3.

   ```json
   "workspaces": [
     "node_modules_custom/*"
   ]
   ```

   Your full `package.json` file should now look something like this:

   ```json
   {
     "name": "my_example_node_project",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
     },
     "repository": {
       "type": "git",
       "url": "git+https://github.com/USER/my_example_node_project.git"
     },
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC",
     "bugs": {
       "url": "https://github.com/USER/my_example_node_project/issues"
     },
     "homepage": "https://github.com/USER/my_example_node_project#readme",
     "workspaces": [
       "node_modules_custom/*"
     ]
   }
   ```
6. Run `npm install` in your project's root directory. NPM will scan-through any directories designated as a workspaces (Step 5) and create symbolic links for the module folders therein.
7. If the process was completed successfully `./node_modules` will now contain your under-development dependency module folders as symbolic links. When the contents of any of these folders is altered, Nodemon will automatically detect it and update accordingly. Any non-symbolically-linked files or folders will continue to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

To watch a specific dir under node_modules while continuing to ignore the rest of node_modules, add the negation flag to the node_modules path in ignoreRoot. Specifying ignoreRoot overrides the default, so include the other files that are part of the default.

```
{
  "watch": ["src", "node_modules/(package_to_watch)"],
  "ignoreRoot": [
    ".git",
    ".log",
    ".nyc_output",
    ".sass-cache",
    ".yarn",
    "bower_components",
    "coverage",
    "node_modules/!(package_to_watch)"
  ]
}
```

Thanks @strider for cluing me in on the negation flag.